# Compton Scattering Angle Distribution, and the Klein-Nishina Model

Tags: scattering, simulations, gamma-rays

I have a Geant4 simulation where 662keV photons are going into a detecting volume (Germanium). As expected, when I look at the output of the simulation, these photons undergo Compton scattering and photoelectric absorption.

I have written a python script for analysing this output, where I calculate the scattering angle and plotted them in a histogram:[image: Histogram of Compton scattering angles from a 662keV]

This seems to agree very well with plots I've found online.
*(figure2:  DOI:10.1016/j.nima.2019.163228 )*
[image: Online plot from a paper.]

To round off this piece of work, I wanted to show that my distribution from Geant4 can be inferred from the Klein-Nishina model/the model that the aforementioned paper used.

However, when I plot the differential cross section *(which I understood as akin to 'probability'?)* vs scattering angle of the KN model, they don’t agree. The distribution shape is totally different.

[image: Klein-Nishina Model]

The simulated electrons in the detecting volume aren't free electrons, so I tried adding an Impulse Approximation (Hartree-Fock if that means anything) but it still doesn't line up with the simulation results *(although I'm not entirely sure if I did it right – the maths was slightly heavy for me)*.

**How would I go about showing the agreement between theory (Klein-Nishina or other model) and my histogram?**

And how did the author of the 'relative probability' graph obtain that data; a model that I don't know of, experimental...?

Any help or push in the right direction is **hugely appreciated**. :)

**EDIT**
The answer below yields the below python script - although the vertical scale is off.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = 299792458.0  # meter / second
E = 662000 *1.602176634 * 10**(-19) #incident energy 
h = 6.62607015 * 10**(-34)  # joule second
hbar = h / (2 * np.pi)
me = 9.1093837015 * 10**(-31)  # kilogram

omega = E / hbar #angular freq
R = hbar * omega / (me * c**2) #variable R in solution

def I(t):#define the function I(theta)
    return -np.cos(t) / R**2 + \
           np.log(1 + R * (1 - np.cos(t))) * (1/R - 2/R**2 - 2/R**3) - \
           1 / (2 * R * (1 + R * (1 - np.cos(t)))**2) + \
           1 / (1 + R * (1 - np.cos(t))) * (-2/R**2 - 1/R**3)

def w_prime(t):#Calc angular_freq for scattered photon
    return omega/(1+(hbar*omega/(me*c**2))*(1-np.cos(t)))

def f(t):#calc f(theta), aka the PDF
    return (1/(I(np.pi)-I(0))) * (w_prime(t)/omega)**2 * (omega/w_prime(t) + w_prime(t)/omega -(np.sin(t)**2))*np.sin(t)

theta_vals = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
f_vals=f(theta_vals)

plt.plot(theta_vals, f_vals)
plt.title("PDF")
plt.xlabel("Theta")
plt.ylabel("f(theta)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: what formula did you use to go from probability per d-theta to solid angle?

Comment: The bottom plot (with the solid angle) was from a blog on scipy blog, just a few formating changes. https://scipython.com/blog/the-kleinnishina-formula/ Its the standard Klein-Nishina model by the looks of it. @JEB

Comment: Since your plot has a different y axis, why should they look the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\sigma$ needs to be converted to a probability density function $f(\theta)$, then plot $f(\theta)$.

The well-known cross section for Compton scattering is
$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
=\frac{\alpha^2(\hbar c)^2}{2s}
\left(\frac{\omega'}{\omega}\right)^2
\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega'}+\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\sin^2\theta\right)
$$
where
$$
\omega'=\frac{\omega}{1+\frac{\hbar\omega}{mc^2}(1-\cos\theta)}
$$

We can integrate $d\sigma$ to obtain a cumulative distribution function.
Let $I(\theta)$ be the following integral of $d\sigma$.
(The $\sin\theta$ is due to $d\Omega=\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$)
\begin{equation*}
I(\theta)=
\int
\left(\frac{\omega'}{\omega}\right)^2
\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega'}+\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\sin^2\theta\right)
\sin\theta\,d\theta
\end{equation*}

The solution is
\begin{multline*}
I(\theta)=-\frac{\cos\theta}{R^2}
+\log\big(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\big)\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{2}{R^3}\right)
\\
{}-\frac{1}{2R\big(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\big)^2}
+\frac{1}{1+R(1-\cos\theta)}\left(-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{1}{R^3}\right)
\end{multline*}
where
\begin{equation*}
R=\frac{\hbar\omega}{mc^2}
\end{equation*}

The cumulative distribution function is
\begin{equation*}
F(\theta)=\frac{I(\theta)-I(0)}{I(\pi)-I(0)},
\quad
0\le\theta\le\pi
\end{equation*}

The probability of observing scattered photons in the interval $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$ is
\begin{equation*}
P(\theta_1\le\theta\le\theta_2)=F(\theta_2)-F(\theta_1)
\end{equation*}

Differentiate $F(\theta)$ to obtain normalized probability density function
$f(\theta)$.
$$
f(\theta)=\frac{dF(\theta)}{d\theta}
=\frac{1}{I(\pi)-I(0)}
\left(\frac{\omega'}{\omega}\right)^2
\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega'}+\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\sin^2\theta\right)
\sin\theta
$$

Note that if we had carried through the $\alpha^2(\hbar c)^2/2s$ in $I(\theta)$,
it would have canceled out in $F(\theta)$.

Comment: I don't really understand how this answer can be correct. I(theta) is everywhere negative, but what is being integrated is positive definite